# Unity - Can I add CharacterController component to 2D sprite in 2D game?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Up to this point I've been making 3D games in Unity and I've been using CharacterController.Move() for moving player most of the times. I'm currently making a 2D platformer which is the first time I'm doing a 2D project in Unity. I'm trying to figure out what would be the best way to move characters around. I think that it's better to write my own controller than to use rigidbody for movement. Rigidbodies may give nice smooth movement, but own controller gives me more flexibility and control over how moving characters work.

My question is: can I add CharacterController component to my 2D player and use its Move() method to move player? Or perhaps CharacterController should be used only for 3D games?

Answer (score 0):

At the end the position of a gameobject is always given by the transform.position.
RigidBodies (RigidBody2D in your case) will handle the transform on physic update loop but at the end the transform position will be changed.

So if you don't want to use physic you can just set the target position to the transform position.

```
transform.position = newPosition;
```

If you want to use a rigidbody you can set the position like this

```
rigidBody2D.MovePosition(newPosition)
```